# `Currency::create_deposit` of `pallet_balance` fail on actual runtime but passes on mock rutime

Tags: benchmarking, balances, benchmark, tcurrency

The benchmark is written as:

```rust
     one_extrinsic {
        let caller: <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId = make_account::<T>(1);

        assert_eq!(
            <T as crate::Config>::Currency::deposit_creating(&caller, 10_000_000_u32.into()).peek(),
            10_000_000_u32.into(),
        );
        
        // ..

    }: _(/* .. */)
    verify {
        // ..
    }
```

where `<T as crate::Config>::Currency` is instance of `pallet_balances`

When running `cargo test bench_one_extrinsic --features runtime-benchmarks` the test is completed.

But where running the actual benchmark `./collator benchmark pallet ..` The statement fails with

```
 left: `0`,
 right: `10000000`', /../src/benchmarking.rs:164:9    
Error: Input("Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n    0: 0x4cbb85 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your actual runtime's `ExistentialDeposit`.

`10_000_000_u32` might not be enough to create an account.

And people usually use `0` in mocking.